# Hadith about monthly payments

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I have heard this hadith but regretfully, forgot to take note of the details. Here are the details I can recall:

> The Messenger (piece and blessings be upon him) learned that someone
>   he loved bought a few things to be paid in monthly payments in six
>   months (I think he got married). He addressed to him, "How do you know you
>   will live for six months?"